# Approach for Laravel ticket buy payment

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel application that sells ticket to an event. A user comes, fills His info (name adress etc) then presses a Button, i Store the info in session then inputs His creditcard info then i make a request to the Api with the info + the amount i want to withdraw then the Api returns with the status: succes or declined. If the answer is success i Store the user and the tranzaction and send the ticket to His email. If the answer is declined i delete the session with all the info. 
Is this a good approach?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be storing people's credit card details, which is **NOT** a good approach. Use an API like Stripe.com the handle cards for you.

I save a user to a customer table when they enter their details, then I send them to my stripe integration. Depending on the success or decline of the status of stripe, I then update the tuple for that customer accordingly.

Comment: How do you handle the response? How do you get the declined or success status from Api? I seen Most apis redirect to a route like /home after the payment is completed, but how do i update the user in the customer table that he paid? Or delete the customer if the payment was declined

Comment: By doing `try ... catch` and then handling the different error codes that come back. If no error code comes back then you can confirm success using `if($charge->paid ==true) { // do stuff }`. See [this blog post](http://www.larryullman.com/2013/01/09/writing-the-php-code-to-process-payments-with-stripe/) for details of the approach.